# Drone.io configuration for C++ with Boost libraries

Tags: c++, continuous-integration

I want to configure drone.io to automatically test my C++ project. Unfortunately build fails each time, because SCons cannot find headers that i just installed. I started with this:

```
sudo apt-get install g++ bison flex libgmp-dev glpk libboost-all-dev scons
echo 2 | sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
scons -Q runProgramsTests
```

but each time [build failed](https://drone.io/github.com/MateuszKubuszok/MasterThesis/7) with a message:

```
$ scons -Q runProgramsTests
Your environment does not seem to have header <boost/container/map.hpp>!!
Your environment does not seem to have header <boost/container/set.hpp>!!
Your environment does not seem to have header <boost/container/vector.hpp>!!
Invalid compiler/libraries installation - build terminated!!
```

The part of build script responsible for this message looks like this:

```
# Assuming that instalation is valid unless proved otherwise
validInstallation = True

conf = Configure(env)

# C++ check
if not conf.CheckCXX():
    print('Your environment/C++ compiler is not configured/installed correctly!!')
    validInstallation = False

# Header check
for header in [
    # standard libraries
    'algorithm', 'cstdlib', 'iomanip',
    'iostream',  'fstream', 'sstream',
    'memory',
    'stdexcept', 'string',  'utility',
    # boost libraries
    'boost/scoped_ptr.hpp',
    'boost/shared_ptr.hpp',
    'boost/weak_ptr.hpp',
    'boost/algorithm/string.hpp',
    'boost/assign.hpp',
    'boost/bimap/bimap.hpp',
    'boost/container/map.hpp',
    'boost/container/set.hpp',
    'boost/container/vector.hpp',
    'boost/program_options.hpp',
    'boost/range/adaptor/map.hpp',
    'boost/range/adaptor/reversed.hpp',
    # Flex library
    'FlexLexer.h',
    # GNU Multiple Precision library
    'gmpxx.h',
    # GNU Linear Package Kit
    'glpk.h'
]:
    if not conf.CheckCXXHeader(header):
        print('Your environment does not seem to have header <'+header+'>!!')
        validInstallation = False
```

If that matters whole `SConstruct` content can be found [here](https://github.com/MateuszKubuszok/MasterThesis/blob/master/SConstruct).

I don't understand why some Boost packages are found, while some are not. On droid.io page I found information that archived artifacts produced by project cannot exceed 10MB - but there was no information on limit of installed libraries.

Running `sudo ldconfig` before calling `scons` didn't helped, and so didn't help settings manually environment variables:

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include
```

Did I missed something? After all I installed `libboost-all-dev` which should contain ALL of Boost libraries and headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the reason: drone.io uses an old version of Ubuntu (precise) which uses version 1.46 of Boost library by default, while Boost.Container package was added in 1.48 release.

After modifing setup to:

```
sudo apt-get install bison flex glpk libboost1.48-all-dev
echo 2 | sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
scons -Q runProgramsTests
```

everything works as expected.